IFERROR *error*
not sure why it’s returning “0” despite asking it to return blank (“”).
Need it to return blank when corresponding column B is blank


XLOOKUP() function returns an error only when it can't find the lookup_value in the lookup_array. To override this one can use either IFNA() or IFERROR(), however when the return_array is empty for the specific lookup_value it doesn't returns an error instead it returns an empty output which behaves like a zero.
You can try the following method to overcome this problem.
=IF(XLOOKUP(B7, Roster!D:D, Roster!B:B)="","",XLOOKUP(B7, Roster!D:D, Roster!B:B))


Or, using LET()
=LET(α, XLOOKUP(B7, Roster!D:D, Roster!B:B), IF(α="","",α))


Or, Incorporating the LEN() function:
=LET(α, XLOOKUP(B7, Roster!D:D, Roster!B:B), IF(LEN(α)=0,"",α))


The above phenomenon is applicable to VLOOKUP() and INDEX()+MATCH()/XMATCH() as well.

Note that using custom formatting also, one can hide the 0 that is using General;; or #,##.00;; based on the preferences.


Since empty values are returned as zero, you could explicitly return a blank either with (no need for IFERROR):
=XLOOKUP(
    B7,
    Sheet2!D:D,
    IF(ISBLANK(Roster!B:B), "", Roster!B:B),
    ""
)

or, if the return values are all text:
=XLOOKUP(B7, Roster!D:D, Roster!B:B,"") & ""


The issue likely arises when the XLOOKUP function doesn't find a match. In such cases, it might return a zero value by default, which is then displayed by the IFERROR function.
Try Refining the XLOOKUP Function
To ensure that a blank value is returned when column B is empty, we need to modify the XLOOKUP function to handle non-matches appropriately. Here's the revised formula:
Excel
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(B7, Roster!D:D, Roster!B:B, "", 0), "")
